# RabbitMQ Can't Send and Receive from same process

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm working through my first steps with RabbitMQ and have a question on why this didn't work.

The basic tutorial (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html) has one executable to send to the broker and another to receive it.

I ran this code through a single console app in Visual Studio and couldn't receive any messages.

If I take the "Receive" code and put it into a separate console app and open that, I get the message (no other code changes).

Can someone explain why I'm not able to have both in the same process?  I had figured that the connection factory would handle independent connections accordingly regardless of whether it was the same process or not.

---

For the sake of completeness (though I doubt it's required), here's the code that didn't work until I pulled out the "Receiver" code and put it into it's own console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Receiver.Receive();
        Console.WriteLine("receiver set up");

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        Console.WriteLine("sending...");
        Test.Send();

        // can also reverse order of send/receive methods, same result

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}


public class Receiver
{
    public static void Receive() {

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };

        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection()) {

            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel()) {

                channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);

                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) => {

                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("=====================");
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("=====================");

                };

                channel.BasicConsume("hello", true, consumer);

            }

        }

    }

}

public class Test
{

    public static void Send() {

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };

        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection()) {

            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel()) {

                channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);

                string message = "Check it!";

                var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                channel.BasicPublish("", "hello", null, body);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think code has a problem. When you send message then Receive connection and channel already dead (Dispose called).

Standard code from RabbitMQ site:

```
    using(var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using(var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                             durable: false,
                             exclusive: false,
                             autoDelete: false,
                             arguments: null);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
        };
        channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello",
                             noAck: true,
                             consumer: consumer);

        Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

`connection` and `channel` are yet alive when client received message.

Comment: You were correct... I had my Console.ReadKey line outside of the using blocks for the receiver, which effectively means I'm not keeping the connection open (letting it dispose before it had a chance to receive).  Apologies for my previous comment questioning your suggestion.  Thanks!